# Specifying colours in a shapefile

Tags: r

how i can specify my own colours in a shapefile. here is a code i ran

```
nig$NAME_1<- factor(nig$NAME_1,
                    levels=c("Abia", "Adamawa", "Akwa Ibom", 
                                       "Anambra", "Bauchi", "Bayelsa",
                                       "Benue", "Borno", "Cross River",
                                       "Delta", "Ebonyi","Edo", "Ekiti", "Enugu",
                                       "Federal Capital Territory","Gombe",
                                       "Imo", "Jigawa", "Kaduna","Kano", "Katsina",
                                       "Kebbi", "Kogi", "Kwara", "Lagos", "Nasarawa",
                                       "Niger", "Ogun", "Ondo", "Osun", "Oyo", "Plateau",
                                       "Rivers", "Sokoto", "Taraba", "Yobe", "Zamfara"),
                              labels=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,1,3,5,1,4,2,1,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,5,
                                       4,4,5,5,5,5,4,3,6,2,2,6)
```

but i am still not able to control the colours i want. the outcome still come with default colours and i want to specify my own colours. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) which includes a code example which others could run and a snippet of your data or some fake data. As is your code only shows the conversion to a `factor`. But you did not provide any information about the code and packages you use to create your map (??) and how you assign the colors.